# How to pass sudo\root password to a Linux command using Free Pascal

Tags: linux, shell, freepascal, lazarus, elevated-privileges

Most of the other questions about this seem to be C related. I am using [Free Pascal](http://freepascal.org) and the [Lazarus IDE](http://lazarus.freepascal.org), version 2.4.0 and 0.9.30 respectively.

I am creating a GUI that calls and passes arguments to a Linux command. I don't want my users to have to run the whole GUI using sudo\root, but rather be prompted for the password at the appropriate time.

I am using `TProcess` to call the Linux commands and pass and read values. I can't work out, though, how to pass the `sudo` password to the command from my own program?

To give an example, take the following normal command line:

```
dd if=/dev/hda1 of=~/image.dd
Enter sudo password:
```

My program is calling `dd`, passing it the `if` and `of` values from a GUI interface - it then needs to gather and pass the `sudo` password to `dd`.

Comment: Can anyone tell or show me an example of how it's been done using another language, then, and perhaps from that I can work out how to apply it to Free Pascal. ?? 

Thanks

Ted

Comment: What about using TProcess to run gksudo instead of running the command directly?

Answer (score 3):

A little bit old, but - use pkexec in front of your command, like: 
pkexec ls /root

You will have each time the GUI info for entering root password.
Tested on LinuxMint

Answer (score 2):

On the premise that you're already using `TProcess`, instead of issuing the command line call directly to `dd` you can use one of the following established methods of invoking `su`/`sudo`:

- `gksudo` ([Ubuntu natty man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gksudo.1.html))
- `kdesudo` ([Ubuntu natty man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/kdesudo.1.html))